# Connecting Linux to 5G WiFi, whereas on 2.4G works just fine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have an quirky issue connecting my Linux machine to WiFi router only on 5Ghz band, whereas on 2.4Ghz everything works fine(, but limiting the internet bandwidth severly).
I suppose that's not router fault, because I'm able to connect my Galaxy Note 10 using 5Ghz band with full speed. I suspect that is simply a Linux configuration problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 with 5.8.0-41-generic kernel and Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter.

But let's start at the very beginning. I could suspect that the problem may have someting with switching to Ubuntu 20.10, but I'm not in 100% certain. I've discovered that **iw reg** setting was erased after some system updates:

```
# iw reg get
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

# iw reg set PL
# iw reg get
global
country PL: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

The current settings of my WiFi router are:

```
2.4Ghz
802.11 Mode: Mixed (802.11b, 802.11g and 802.11n)
Channel: Auto (Current Ch. 1)
Bandwidth: Auto
Power: 100

5Ghz
802.11 Mode: Mixed (802.11a and 802.11n/ac)
Channel: Auto (Current Ch. 100/80)
Bandwidth: Auto
Power: 100
```

I think that listing below could be helpful:

```
# iw list
Wiphy phy0
    wiphy index: 0
    max # scan SSIDs: 1
    max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
    Band 1:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5160 MHz [32] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5170 MHz [34] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5250 MHz [50] (disabled)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5270 MHz [54] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5290 MHz [58] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5310 MHz [62] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5330 MHz [66] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5350 MHz [70] (disabled)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
            * 5370 MHz [74] (disabled)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
            * 5390 MHz [78] (disabled)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
            * 5410 MHz [82] (disabled)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
            * 5430 MHz [86] (disabled)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
            * 5450 MHz [90] (disabled)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
            * 5470 MHz [94] (disabled)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5490 MHz [98] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5510 MHz [102] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5530 MHz [106] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5550 MHz [110] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5570 MHz [114] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5590 MHz [118] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5610 MHz [122] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5630 MHz [126] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5650 MHz [130] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5670 MHz [134] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5690 MHz [138] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5710 MHz [142] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5725 MHz [145] (disabled)
            * 5730 MHz [146] (disabled)
            * 5735 MHz [147] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5740 MHz [148] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5750 MHz [150] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5755 MHz [151] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5760 MHz [152] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5770 MHz [154] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5775 MHz [155] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5780 MHz [156] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5790 MHz [158] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5795 MHz [159] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5800 MHz [160] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5810 MHz [162] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5815 MHz [163] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5820 MHz [164] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5830 MHz [166] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5840 MHz [168] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5850 MHz [170] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5860 MHz [172] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5870 MHz [174] (disabled)
            * 5880 MHz [176] (disabled)
            * 5890 MHz [178] (disabled)
            * 5900 MHz [180] (disabled)
            * 5910 MHz [182] (disabled)
            * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
            * 5930 MHz [186] (disabled)
            * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
            * 5950 MHz [0] (disabled)
            * 5960 MHz [2] (disabled)
            * 5970 MHz [4] (disabled)
            * 5980 MHz [6] (disabled)
            * 5990 MHz [8] (disabled)
            * 6000 MHz [10] (disabled)
            * 6010 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 6020 MHz [14] (disabled)
            * 6030 MHz [16] (disabled)
            * 6040 MHz [18] (disabled)
            * 6050 MHz [20] (disabled)
            * 6060 MHz [22] (disabled)
            * 6070 MHz [24] (disabled)
            * 6080 MHz [26] (disabled)
            * 6090 MHz [28] (disabled)
            * 6100 MHz [30] (disabled)
            * 6110 MHz [32] (disabled)
            * 6120 MHz [34] (disabled)
            * 6130 MHz [36] (disabled)
            * 6140 MHz [38] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * connect
         * disconnect
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports scan flush.
    Supported extended features:
```

I would appreciate any clues what is happening and how to utilize 5Ghz band.